# Spring for Android: REST server

Tags: java, android, spring, spring-mvc

I was hoping to create a client-server Android application - both REST server and client to run on the same device. I've come across many SO questions about REST server that has no answers, so haven't been very helpful there.

I stumbled on [Spring for Android](https://projects.spring.io/spring-android/), and could find many YouTube videos and tutorials using Spring for Android as REST *client*, but hardly any on server.

Please could someone tell me if it can run as REST server on Android? If not--and this has been asked before--are there suitable libraries/frameworks that works OOB?

Answer (score 0):

You can use skornei restserver, this is a REST server for android apps:

this is a get started
https://github.com/skornei/restserver/wiki/Getting-started

This is a sample code to build rest server like a spring boot rest controller into a web application, BUT in this case is a Android App. skornei restserver is a wonderful lib and helpme Very a Lot, see the example code of rest controller

```java
@RestController("/ping")
public class PingController {

    @GET
    @RequiresAuthentication
    public void ping() {
        System.out.println("work!");        
    }

    @POST
    @Produces(ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Accept(ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public TestEntity test(Context context, RequestInfo request, ResponseInfo response, TestEntity testEntity) {
        return new TestEntity(testEntity.getTest() + ":test");
    }

    private static String getStackTrace(Throwable throwable) {
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        throwable.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(stringWriter));
        return stringWriter.toString();
    }

    @ExceptionHandler
    @Produces(ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public void handleThrowable(Throwable throwable, ResponseInfo response) {
        String throwableStr = getStackTrace(throwable);
        response.setBody(throwableStr.getBytes());
    }
}
```

*** Very important step:
Do you need also, Android config for a custom application and add It to your Android Manifest like this:

```java
public class YouApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        RestServerManager.initialize(this);
    }
}
```

And register the application on AndroidManifest:

```xml
<application
.
.
.
        android:name="com.you.yourapp.ApplicationEx"
.
.
.
/>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30407695)

Comment: ok, i'll do it, i'm adjusting, but it's the official lib documentation on github, if the page changes, it's because the lib itself has changed. But i send now a piece of code to enrich the answer mf.

Comment: Hey @procastinator see now. Tks for your comments.